# Log-concavity of the difference of the second anti-derivative of Gaussians

Tags: real-analysis, convexity, convex-analysis, gaussian

I would like to prove the following but I couldn't manage to do it. Let $a>b>0$ be two real numbers. Let $f$ be the function defined as:

$$\forall \sigma>0, ~\forall x\in\mathbb{R},~f_\sigma(x):=\sigma e^{-x^2/\sigma^2}+\sqrt{\pi}x\text{erf}\left(\frac{x}{\sigma}\right).$$

**I would like to show that $f_a-f_b$ is log-concave.**

One can see $f_\sigma$ as the function that, differentiated two times, gives the gaussian function (with a scaling factor) of mean $0$ and deviation $\sigma$. More formally, one can compute the second derivative and show that:
$$f_\sigma''(x) = \frac{e^{-x^2/\sigma^2}}{2\sigma}.$$

Numerically, I am pretty sure that this statement is true. I tried to compute the second derivative of the $\log(f_a-f_b)$ but without sucess (the derivatives are too diffucult to analyse).

Any hints or solutions will be highly appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: (i) "One can see $f$ as the second anti-derivative of the gaussian distribution (with a scaling factor)." -- What is $f$? What is "**the** second anti-derivative"? Of what "gaussian distribution"? What is a "second anti-derivative" of a distribution (which latter is a measure)? (ii) Do you have an inequality between $a$ and $b$?

Comment: Thank you @IosifPinelis for asking details. I updated the post, I hope it is clearer.

Comment: "One can see $f_\sigma$ as the function that, differentiated two times, gives the gaussian distribution (with a scaling factor) of mean $0$ and deviation $\sigma$." -- As I noted, a distribution cannot be the second derivative of a function. Also, in this case, the second derivative will also depend on $a$.

Comment: I updated the post, is it correct now ?

Comment: "where $Z$ does not depend on $\sigma$"... How come? I think this post may require quite a bit of work.

Comment: I can put the detail of the computation but I think it will turn the post into a confusing one (since this computation is not the objective of the post...). What do you think ? (I wrote down the exact result).

Comment: What? Here, $f_\sigma$ is defined as a formula involving both $\sigma$ and $a$, then we write $f_a$ ??  and even more, we write $f_b$ ??

Comment: Sorry, $a$ and $\sigma$ were the same. Now it is correct but if you think is better, I can rewrite another post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This conjecture is true.

Indeed, for $h:=\ln(f_a-f_b)$ and real $x\ne0$ we have
\begin{equation}
    h'(x)=R(x):=\frac{F(x)}{G(x)},
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation}
    F(x):=\sqrt{\pi }
   \left(\text{erf}\left(\frac{x}{a}\right)-\text{erf}\left(\frac{x}{b}\right)\right), 
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
     G(x):=  a e^{-x^2/a^2}+\sqrt{\pi } x\,
   \text{erf}\left(\frac{x}{a}\right)-b
   e^{-x^2/b^2}-\sqrt{\pi } x \,  \text{erf}\left(\frac{x}{b}\right); 
\end{equation}
note that $G(0)=a-b>0$ and $G'(x)=\sqrt{\pi }
   \left(\text{erf}\left(\frac{x}{a}\right)-\text{erf}\left(\frac{x}{b}\right)\right)>0$ for real $x>0$, so that $G>0$ on $[0,\infty)$.

Since the function $h$ is smooth and even, it is enough to show that $R$ is decreasing on $(0,\infty)$. In what follows, $a>b>0$ and $x>0$, unless otherwise indicated.

Let
\begin{equation}
    R_1(x):=\frac{F'(x)}{G'(x)},  
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
    R_2(x):=\frac{F''(x)}{G''(x)}
    = -\frac{2 x \left(a^3 e^{x^2/a^2}-b^3
   e^{x^2/b^2}\right)}{a^2 b^2 \left(a e^{x^2/a^2}-b e^{x^2/b^2}\right)};
\end{equation}
note that $R_2(x)$ is undefined at $x=x_{a,b}$, where
\begin{equation}
    x_{a,b}:=a b \sqrt{\frac{\ln a-\ln b}{a^2-b^2}}. 
\end{equation}

Then
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
    H(t)&:=R'_2(x)\frac{1}{2} a^3 b^3 \left(a e^{x^2/a^2}-b e^{x^2/b^2}\right)^2 \\ 
&   =a^4 \left(b^2-2 t\right)-a b^5 e^{\left(\frac{1}{b^2}-\frac{1}{a^2}\right)t}+a^2 \left(b^4+4 b^2
   t\right)-a^5 b e^{\left(\frac{1}{a^2}-\frac{1}{b^2}\right)t}-2 b^4 t,    
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
where $t:=x^2>0$, and
\begin{equation}
    H'(t)\frac{ab}{a^2-b^2}=H_1(u):=\frac{a^4}{u}-2 a^3 b+2 a b^3-b^4 u,
\end{equation}
where $u:=e^{\left(\frac{1}{a^2}-\frac{1}{b^2}\right)t}>1$. The only root $u$ of the equation $H_1(u)=0$ that may be positive is
\begin{equation}
    u_{a,b}:=\frac{a b^3-a^3 b+\sqrt{a^6 b^2-a^4 b^4+a^2 b^6}}{b^4}. 
\end{equation}
Replacing now $e^{\left(\frac{1}{a^2}-\frac{1}{b^2}\right)t}$ and $e^{\left(\frac{1}{b^2}-\frac{1}{a^2}\right)t}$ in the expression for $H(t)$ by $u_{a,b}$ and $1/u_{a,b}$, respectively, we see that the condition $H'(t)=0$ for some real $t>0$ will imply
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
    H(t)&=a^4 \left(-\frac{b^4}{-a^2+\sqrt{a^4-a^2 b^2+b^4}+b^2}+2 b^2-2
   t\right) \\ 
   &-a^2 b^2 \left(\sqrt{a^4-a^2 b^2+b^4}-4 t\right)-2
   b^4 t,   
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
which is a rather simple algebraic expression, which is actually $<0$ (still assuming $a>b>0$ and $t>0$).
So, $H(t)<0$ at any critical point $t>0$ of $H$.
Also, $H(0)=-a (a - b)^2 b (a^2 + a b + b^2)<0$ and $H(\infty-):=\lim_{t\to\infty}H(t)=-\infty$. So, $H(t)<0$ for all real $t\ge0$.

So, $R_2$ is decreasing on $(0,x_{a,b})$ and on $(x_{a,b},\infty)$.

Also, $R_1>0$ on $(0,x_{a,b})$, $R_1(x_{a,b})=0$, $R_1<0$ on $(x_{a,b},\infty)$, $R_1(0+)=\infty$, and $R_1(\infty-)=-\infty$.

So, by [Table 1.1](https://eudml.org/doc/128522), $R_1$ is decreasing on $(0,\infty)$. Also, $R'(0)=-\frac2{ab}<0$ and $R(\infty-)=-\infty$. So, again by [Table 1.1](https://eudml.org/doc/128522), $R$ is decreasing on $(0,\infty)$. $\quad\Box$

Comment: Thank you very much for this very clever answer @Iosif Pinelis :)