# Inequality involving convolution roots

Tags: real-analysis, gaussian, convolution, zeroes

I am struggling with the following problem. Let $f$ be a real smooth function. Let assume that $f$ is:

- increasing
- strictly convex on $(-\infty,0)$
- strictly concave on $(0,+\infty)$

Let $\sigma>0$ a real numbers and $G_\sigma$the gaussian functions with mean 0 and deviation $\sigma$. We know that these 3 functions:

- $f''$
- $f''*G_\sigma$
- $f*G_\sigma -f$

have then only one root on $\mathbb{R}$ (respectively in 0, $x_1^\sigma$ and $x_{2}^\sigma$). (I can provide further details on that if you want, especially for the third one.)

**I am numerically convinced that we have for all $\sigma>0$, $x_2^\sigma$ is between 0 and $x_1^\sigma$ (or the other way around):**
$$\min(0,x_1^\sigma)\leq x_{2}^\sigma\leq\max(0,x_1^\sigma).$$

Does anyone have a solution, an hint to prove this inequality or a name of a related topic ?

Thank you very much.

*NB1: the symbol $*$ denotes the convolution operator.*

*NB2: I managed to do it for $\sigma$ tending to zero but not more.*

*NB3:*

- *(2nd item) We know that a function $f$ has a single inflection point, the convolution $f''*G_\sigma$ has a single 0 since the gaussian kernels are Polya frequency function.*
- *(3rd item) If you integrate by part two times the third convolution, it will lead the convolution $f''*(A_\sigma-A_\epsilon)$ where $A_\sigma$ and $A_\epsilon$ are second anti-derivative of $G_\sigma$ and $G_\epsilon$ (the first and second derivative need to decrease quickly and we assume that all is well defined). As done by @Iosif Pinelis in [this post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/453122/log-concavity-of-the-difference-of-the-second-anti-derivative-of-gaussians?noredirect=1#comment1172100_453122), the function $A_\sigma-A_\epsilon$ is log-concave and then a Polya frequency function. Thus, the convolution have the variation dimishing property. Finally, the third convolution has at most one zero (and has by studying the sign in $\pm\infty$ and letting $\epsilon\to0$)*

Comment: "I can provide further details on that"... Can you do this indeed?

Comment: I have added some details in the NB3&4. Tell me if it is not clear. Thank you!

Comment: (i) What is your definition of a Polya frequency function? It seems that it is such that any log-concave function is a Polya frequency function in your sense. But then, how do you get the variation diminishing property? (ii) "I managed to do it for $\sigma$ tending to zero." What does this mean? (iii) "I am numerically convinced" ... Using what functions $f$?

Comment: (i) I found this property in [this old paper](https://www.pnas.org/doi/pdf/10.1073/pnas.34.4.164) (ii) I managed to prove that $x_1^\sigma-x_2^\sigma$ and $x_2^\sigma -0$ have the same sign for $\sigma \to 0$ (iii) I have used even unusual functions such as $\log(1+x)$ if $x\geq0$, $\text{arctan}(x)$ otherwise.