# Prove concavity of real valued function on the non-negative real axis

Tags: real-analysis, convexity

Fix $\alpha >0$ and define $f_{\alpha}(x) := \ln(\Phi(\alpha-x)-\Phi(-\alpha-x))$, where $\Phi(x)$ is the normal cumulative density function. For some research, I am trying to verify that the function $f_{\alpha}'$ (its derivative) is concave on $x \geq 0$. This is given by:

$$f_{\alpha}'(x) = \frac{\varphi(\alpha + x) - \varphi(\alpha - x)}{\int_{-\alpha - x}^{\alpha-x} \varphi(t)dt}$$

where $\varphi(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-x^2/2}$. Since this function is $C^2$ we can try analysing its second derivative. Immediate differentiation gives us that (we omit the $\alpha$ dependence in the notation):

$$f''' = \frac{(g''')g^2 - (3g''g')g + 2(g')^3}{g^3}$$

where:

$$g(x) = \Phi(\alpha-x) -\Phi(-\alpha-x)\\
g'(x) = \varphi(\alpha+x)-\varphi(\alpha-x) \\
g''(x) = -[\varphi(\alpha+x)(\alpha+x) + \varphi(\alpha-x)(\alpha-x)] \\
g'''(x) = [(\alpha+x)^2-1]\varphi(\alpha+x)-[(\alpha-x)^2-1]\varphi(\alpha-x) $$

It is easy to check that $f'''(0)=0$. But, any ideas on how can I verify that $f'''(x) \leq 0$ for $x \geq 0$? Observe that $g(x) > 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, so we just need to focus on the numerator. Plotting it for some values of $\alpha$ suggests that this is true.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure in $\int_{-\alpha - x}^{\alpha-x} \varphi(t)dt$? In your formulation $f_{\alpha}'(x)$ is not cocave.

Comment: Why is $f_{\alpha}'(x)$ not concave on the region $x \geq 0$? I would like this to be true, so far I do not know but some computations suggest it. @user64494

Comment: Maybe you could use something similar to https://mathoverflow.net/questions/453122/log-concavity-of-the-difference-of-the-second-anti-derivative-of-gaussians